# How can I duplicate a tab in selenium in a way that works for all browsers?

Tags: selenium, cross-browser

I want to duplicate a tab in selenium. Edge, Firefox and Chrome can all do this, but all of the answers on other questions give solutions (using action groups to press Alt-d, for example) that only work on chrome.

**How can I duplicate a tab in Selenium in a way that works for all browsers?**

Comment: you can write a case function...

Comment: I'm looking for a more elegant way to do it. But I suppose a case function will have to do if there's no other way.

Comment: It's a good question... I don't know of any global convention for all browsers... I'll be surprised if there is... +1 let's see if anyone has any other idea...

Comment: @MosheSlavin: I don't know the chords for every browser, so a list would be a fine answer, especially if nothing else exists.